# Linux - After reboot, I get a Keyboard Interactive Authentication error. All Network traffic closed it seems

Tags: linux, centos, putty

I'm running Centos connecting with Putty.

Starting today, every time I reboot, It forces me to log in as root before it will let me log in with my su. I log into Root, then run `su username` and then lets me log in as that user. However, since this happened the first time, I can't ftp or access http on the server, or even ping. I checked and Apache is running, and so is vsftpd. The firewall isn't running.

Where I should look next to see what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I just tried pinging the domain from within Putty, and got a response. Pinging said domain from my machine times out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it would seem that my IP got blocked by incorrectly trying to log in. Changing IP I can now connect just fine.